# AWS Federated Role Access does not refresh after 1hr with STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am using AWS Federated/Assume role to read and write data into S3. My job takes around 1hr 30 min. By normal profile it's session expiring after 1hr. I tried to use **STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider**. But this also fails.

I was following this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempFederationToken.html

**My Code**

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicSessionCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Policy;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Resource;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Statement;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Statement.Effect;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.actions.S3Actions;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetFederationTokenRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetFederationTokenResult;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MakingRequestsWithFederatedTempCredentials {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "my_bucket";
        String federatedUser = "fed_user";
        String resourceARN = "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucketName;

        try {
            AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            GetFederationTokenRequest federationTokenRequest = new GetFederationTokenRequest();
            federationTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(3600);
            federationTokenRequest.setName(federatedUser);

            // Get the temporary security credentials.
            GetFederationTokenResult federationTokenResult = stsClient.getFederationToken(federationTokenRequest);
            Credentials sessionCredentials = federationTokenResult.getCredentials();

            // Package the session credentials as a BasicSessionCredentials
            // object for an Amazon S3 client object to use.
            BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                    sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                    sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(resourceARN, federatedUser).withStsClient(stsClient).build())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            //here my spark job is being called..
            // using s3Client
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The S3 client may have its credentials updated -but your spark work happening across the cluster won't be picking up any new values.

You can change the lifespan of assumed roles to be 12h? you should be able to ask for a set of role credentials for that duration & so your job will have valid session secrets through its whole life.